# htmlspecialchars utf-8 returns empty string

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, htmlspecialchars

I'm doing a .php RSS generator and I have a problem trying to get data from my database in this line:

```
<description><![CDATA[<?=htmlspecialchars(utf8_substr($row['texto'], 0, 100), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') ?>...]]></description>
```

Some entries show just fine, and others wont return any text... Any idea on what could be wrong?

This is all the code:

```
<?php

require('php/config.php');
require('php/db.php');
require('php/utils.php');

header("Content-type: application/xml");

$db = new TSQL('SELECT * FROM entradas WHERE estado = 1 ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 20');
if ( $db->executeQuery() ) {

?><?='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>' ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>Tu Secreto</title>
        <link>http://www.tusecreto.com.ar/</link>
        <description>TuSecreto / No se lo cuentes a nadie, contaselo a todos</description>
        <language>es-ar</language>
        <copyright>TuSecreto (C) 2005-<?php print strftime("%Y", time()); ?></copyright>
        <lastBuildDate><?=strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S ", $row['fecha']) ?></lastBuildDate>
        <atom:link href="http://www.tusecreto.com.ar/rss.php" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <docs>http://www.tusecreto.com.ar/rss.php</docs>
        <generator>TuSecreto RSS Generator v1.0</generator>
        <ttl>10</ttl>
        <? while ($row = $db->getRow(MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <item>
            <title><?=($row['sexo'] == MUJER)?'Mujer':'Hombre' ?> | <?=$row['edad'] ?> <?="A\xC3\xB1os" ?></title>
            <description><![CDATA[<?=htmlspecialchars(utf8_substr($row['texto'], 0, 100), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') ?>...]]></description>
            <link>http://www.tusecreto.com.ar/<?=$row['id'] ?></link>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.tusecreto.com.ar/<?=$row['id'] ?></guid>
            <pubDate><?=strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S ", $row['fecha']) ?></pubDate>
        </item>
        <?php } ?>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

This is one result that returns an empty string:

> una vez en el colectivo (sentada en el asiento individual) me dormí y cuando doblo me caí en el pasillo re mal! se mataron de la risa todos!! hasta el colectivero! Pasalo y comento con mi Facebook. E.P.

Comment: Give an example of some that are resulting in the return of an empty string.

Comment: How is `utf8_substr` defined?

Comment: I've updated the post with all the code and one result... Maybe it's because the accented characters? "dormí". Is spanish...

Answer (score 21):

Your code uses `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')`. Quoting from the [manpage](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

> If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the
>   given encoding an empty string will be returned, unless either the
>   ENT_IGNORE or ENT_SUBSTITUTE flags are set.

Use e.g. `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'utf-8')` as a quick workaround.

If invalid input is indeed your problem, of course, you should find out why `utf8_substr($row['texto'], 0, 100)` does not return a valid UTF-8 string in the first place.

Comment: (1) The default isn't `ENT_QUOTES` but `ENT_COMPAT`. (2) What the doc says about `ENT_IGNORE`: "Silently discard invalid code unit sequences instead of returning an empty string. Using this flag is discouraged as it » may have security implications." (3) `ENT_SUBSTITURE` is only available starting from PHP 5.4.0

Comment: Definitely do not ignore this error with `ENT_IGNORE` as this has security implications, per the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is still unresolved, and I recently found a solution to a problem I had similar to this: abnormal characters would make the function print an empty string. Therefore I intend to place my input.

In the flags area, add " `| ENT_SUBSTITUTE`" and change the encoding type to "cp1252." The `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` flag will ensure to replace any unrecognized characters instead of creating an empty string. The encoding type "cp1252" is Windows-specific however, and I suggest looking at the other types on the manual page if it does not work (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). (I presumed why this encoding worked for me was because my server is running on Windows IIS)

EDIT: You also have the option to remove the encoding type in XML files, and PHP will work fine with it.